# Verwendung von Konjunktiv II in Wikipediaartikel

Tags: subjunctive

In einem Wikipediaartikel steht folgender Text:

> "Die DGE empfiehlt vegane Ernährung für Schwangere, Stillende, Säuglinge, Kinder und Jugendliche ausdrücklich nicht. Diese speziellen Bevölkerungsgruppen ***hätten*** ein höheres Risiko für Nährstoffdefizite. Wer sich dennoch vegan ernähren möchte, sollte dauerhaft ein Vitamin-B12-Präparat einnehmen"

Warum verwendet man hier das Wort *hätten* und nicht einfach *haben*? Warum braucht man den Konjunktiv II hier überhaupt?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Weil es sich um indirekte Rede handelt, die der Wikipedia-Autor sich nicht zu eigen macht.

Bei vielen Verbformen ist der *Konjunktiv I* nicht vom *Indikativ* unterscheidbar, so auch bei *haben*. Dann wird die Form des *Konjunktiv II* verwendet.

Davon sind die Wikipedia-Autoren dann aber so verwirrt, dass sie im nächsten Satz *sollte* statt *solle* verwenden, was der richtige *Konjunktiv I* wäre, wogegen der *Konjunktiv II* von *sollen* nicht vom *Indikativ Präteritum* unterscheidbar ist und daher eher nicht verwendet wird.

Comment: Fachleute behaupten, dass 99,9 Prozent der deutschsprachigen Bevölkerung den Konjunktiv I in indirekter Rede nicht richtig einzusetzen in der Lage seien, und dito verhalte es sich mit 95 Prozent der heute tätigen Journalisten. Insbesondere gebe es seit Jahren kaum mehr eine richtige Verwendung von *gebe* vs. *gäbe*. Ach, gäbe es doch nur eine höhere Sprachkultur in der Breite! Dann stünde es auch um den Konjunktiv besser.

Comment: Andererseits finde ich nach eher unfreiwilliger Lektüre kafkaesker Kolportagen im Konjunktiv beider Kategorien den Indikativ gar nicht so übel.

Comment: Den Indikativ könnte man durchaus loben und lieben, böte der Konjunktiv nicht mehr Nuancen des Ausdrucks, auf die zu verzichten einem schwerfiele.

Comment: Und dann sind da noch die, die gleich zum Knojunktiv Futur II greifen würden ...